# Paso de arrays como parámetros en C++

Tags: c++, array, dev-c++, codeblocks, paso-por-referencia

Mi pregunta va, específicamente, por el siguiente procedimiento hecho en C++:

> arr: lo considero como arreglo

> tam: es un parametro de referencia que me representa el tamaño del arreglo. Este tamaño lo pido en el procedimiento.

```
void ingresarNumeros(int *arr, int &tam)
{
   int num2;
   bool band1;
   do{
         cout<<"\t-> Ingrese el tamanio del vector: ";
         cin>>tam;
         if(tam<=0){
            cout<<"\tCantidad no permitida.\n\n";
            band1 = false;
         }
         else{
            band1= true;
         }
   }while(band1==false);
   printf("\n");
   for(int i = 0;i<tam;i++){
      cout<<"\t-> Ingrese un entero: ";
      cin>>num2;
      arr[i] = num2;   //Creo que el problema es en la asignacion
   }
}
```

Este codigo es parte de un trabajo que estoy realizando. El código compila, pero cuando ingreso los números enteros para que se guarden en el arreglo, se cierra. Entonces, concluí que esto sucede cuando se da la asignación:

```
      arr[i]=num2;
```

El problema va que en algunos IDE no me compila este código y en otros sí. Utilizo Codeblocks Version 20.03 y en mi computadora sí compila y funciona como deseo, es decir, sí funciona la asignación. Pero al compilarlo en otras computadoras con el mismo IDE no funciona, y en otras computadoras sí. Caso similar con los IDE, cuando lo compilo en Dev-C++ no funciona correctamente, pero en otras computadoras con el mismo IDE sí funciona. Entonces, ¿Es un error de código, de IDE o de computador? o tal vez, ¿hay algo más que no estoy tomando en cuenta?.

Agradezco mucho su atención y su ayuda.

Comment: Cuando dices que el codigo no compila, puedes compartir los errores que te salen?

Comment: El problema está en la llamada a esa función y cóno le pasas ese array de enteros, si ya tienes reservada memoria para él o no y pare que no y por eso, cuando intentas escribir en el array tu programa se cae por escribir en una zona de memoria que no es tuya. Comparte cómo defines ese array y cómo se lo pasas a esa función.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes una serie de problemas de concepto y diseño en tu código que dan lugar al error que describes. Empecemos por lo principal:

#### La memoria.

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) puedes pedir memoria para una formación<sup>1</sup> de manera automática o de manera dinámica.

La manera automática es especificando un tamaño concreto en el momento de definir la variable:

```
int formacion[10]; // Una formación de '10' enteros.
```

El espacio que puedes pedir para una formación<sup>1</sup> en memoria automática debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación y está limitada al tamaño máximo de la pila, en cambio pidiendo memoria dinámica:

```
int *formacion = new int[tamanyo]; // Una formación de 'tamanyo' enteros
```

El espacio no necesita ser conocido en tiempo de compilación y no tiene la limitación de la pila.

En cualquiera de los dos casos, antes de rellenar una formación<sup>1</sup> hay que reservar espacio para sus elementos.

#### Los parámetros.

Puedes pasar formaciones<sup>1</sup> a funciones como referencia o como puntero, al pasarla como referencia debes especificar también el tamaño:

```
// Una función que recibe una formación de 10 enteros por referencia
void funcion(int (&formacion)[10])
{
    ...
}
```

Si pasas la formación<sup>1</sup> como puntero, pierdes la información del tamaño:

```
// ¿Cuántos elementos tiene 'formacion'? No se sabe
void funcion(int *formacion)
{
    ...
}
```

Pasar formaciones<sup>1</sup> como puntero es compatible tanto con formaciones<sup>1</sup> en memoria automática como en memoria dinámica, sin embargo, pasarlas por referencia sólo es compatible con formaciones<sup>1</sup> en memoria automática; pero en ambos casos debería haber memoria reservada para los elementos de la formación<sup>1</sup>.

#### El desastre.

En tu código estás pasando una formación<sup>1</sup> como puntero y una variable para definir su tamaño, pero en ninguna parte de la función `ingresarNumeros` pides memoria para la formación<sup>1</sup> que recibes en el primer parámetro, en consecuencia cuando asignas valores a los elementos de la formación:

```
arr[i]=num2;
```

Estás asignando datos a memoria que no te pertenece y el programa reacciona dando un fallo en tiempo de ejecución (se cierra), si quieres que el tamaño de la formación<sup>1</sup> sea arbitrario tendrás que usar memoria dinámica:

```
void ingresarNumeros(int *arr, int &tam)
{
    using namespace std;

    int num2;
    bool band1;
    do {
        cout << "\t-> Ingrese el tamanio del vector: ";
        cin >> tam;
        if (tam <= 0) {
            cout << "\tCantidad no permitida.\n\n";
            band1 = false;
        }
        else {
            band1 = true;
        }
    } while(band1 == false);

    arr = new int[tam]; // Pedir tamaño para la formación
    printf("\n");
 
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; ++i) {
        cout << "\t-> Ingrese un entero: ";
        cin >> num2;
        arr[i] = num2;
    }
}
```

Sólo con añadir la petición de memoria en la función ya se arregla tu error, pero la función sigue siendo un desastre:

1. Es mala práctica pedir memoria en un lugar diferente al que se va a usar, el hecho de pasar la formación<sup>1</sup> por puntero (y su tamaño por referencia) nos indica que pretende usarse fuera de la función.
2. Mezclas impresión por consola estilo C++ (`cout`) con estilo C (`printf`) usa sólo uno de ellos (o sea, usa el estilo C++).
3. El código es innecesariamente complicado y extenso. Para lo poco que hace, podría hacerlo con menos complicaciones.
4. Olvida las formaciones<sup>1</sup> usa algún contenedor de C++.

#### Propuesta.

Abordando los problemas listados en el apartado anterior, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

// Devuelve una lista de números, el propio objeto lista almacena su tamaño.
std::list<int> ingresarNumeros()
{
    using namespace std;
    std::list<int> numeros;
    // Si el valor es sin signo, no puede contener valores negativos.
    unsigned tam = 0;

    // Repetimos mientras 'tam' sea cero (cero se interpreta como 'false').
    while (!tam)
    {
        cout << "\t-> Ingrese el tamanio del vector: ";
        cin >> tam;
        if (!tam)
            cout << "\tCantidad no permitida.\n\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i != tam; ++i)
    {
        int numero;
        cout<<"\t-> Ingrese un entero: ";
        cin >> numero;
        numeros.push_back(numero);
    }

    return numeros;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Los numeros son:\n";
    for (const auto &numero : ingresarNumeros())
        std::cout << numero << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHbSsNAEH3OfMW0gk0pLfWuSZoXnwTxCwqyJtt2MJkNe9EH8dvjbhJbohDI7Jk5Z8@cLZpmWVSC9217RlxUrpSYkTJWS1HncMIqMjYHMLZMklBnxDZH4r2WRugXV0utTDyHL4ic8TCyqKVpRCHRc1KI/jC5Z/iGY0N7liVaUeMG1ylA9HmgSmI88dAcIq8ZFcpZzDKcbu0yx6fuXomyCizBpLD09YcsrNIJTtPAIMY8D/1wot1RbiT2KNhSKUpkhY3UNYXTastbDiLf3stOaYy9Z6TOnf9NNp0qLhY0uAvtfqN08JplY6eOUbL1A2N3J9IQyKpx5vD6Jor3uEfmgw0trdN8ys1j4dZaEPexdwEfN3tW5ncWjeKk36fbpVBsLApnFZ73I5j8f8kQ1EhyGPXVDGfp0ZB/r@@2XcMaLvwHl3AF13ADt3AH9/AQwB8)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.